# Cloud9 - Where to Open .profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I really need to manually inspect/edit the ~/.profile on cloud9 but it's really well hidden. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on the gear icon near the top right of the File navigation tree. Enable both `Show home in favorites` and `Show hidden files`. That'll show your Home folder within your file navigation tree and also show all the hidden files within your project. Once you see the `.profile` file, just double click it to edit.